# How to use mean function in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I want to make a raster showing the average values of 12 rasters. I use Raster Calculator and simply add all of them and divide them by 12 but the result is not correct! The max is far less than what it should be! I already used ArcGIS to do the same job and in ArcGIS I use Mean function and it works as expected and correctly. I'm really confused what is wrong! What is the simple function for mean in QGIS?

Comment: the simple funcion for mean is (raster1 + raster2 + raster3 ... )/number_of_rasters, although there are some caveats when you have NULL values